# How can I use `ThenInclude` in generic class in UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, entity-framework-core, unit-of-work

I have generic Repository in my project.

I want to use `ThenInclude()` in Search method of unitofwork

how can i do it?

I use this method but `ThenInclude` does not work

```
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> FindByConditionAsync(
                                         Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,                                              
                                         Func<IQueryable<TEntity>,IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null, 
                                         params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes)
 {
     IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
     foreach (var includ in includes)
     {
         query = query.Include(includ);
     }

     if (filter != null)
     {
         query = query.Where(filter);
     }

     if (orderBy != null)
     {
         query = orderBy(query);
     }

     return await query.ToListAsync();
 }
```

Comment: The goal of UoW/Repository is to abstract/hide the technologies used to implement the DAL, your contract quite tightly binds it to EF Core making it kind of pointless. EF Core already is repostiory/UoW and a strong case can be made about having generic repostiory/UoW on top of it being [anti-pattern](https://bigmachine.io/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/). Especially for such implementations.

Comment: @GuruStron Do you have better Alternative for search and order generic in ef core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case we need to change `params Expression<Func<TEntity, object>>[] includes` to `Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null`.  `IIncludableQueryable<>` now permits us to use `ThenInclude()` and some changes make this method better.

**SampleCode :**

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets the IEnumerable entities based on a conditionally, orderby delegate and include delegate. This method default no-tracking query.
 /// </summary>
 /// <param name="selector">Mannage type of IEnumerable class that you want to return it</param>
 /// <param name="filter">Set condition for filter</param>
 /// <param name="orderBy">For set order of elements</param>
 /// <param name="include">Set include and thenInclude with this</param>
 /// <param name="disableTracking">disable tracking if is true take query AsNoTracking default is true</param>
 /// <typeparam name="TResult">the type of IEnumerable that you want return</typeparam>
 /// <returns>Return IEnumerable TResult type</returns>
 public async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>?> FindByConditionAsync<TResult>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TResult>> selector,
                                              Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
                                              Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
                                              Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, object>> include = null,
                                              bool disableTracking = true)
 {
     IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
    
     query = disableTracking ? query.AsNoTracking() : query.AsTracking();

     if (include != null) query = include(query);

     if (filter != null) query = query.Where(filter);

     if (orderBy != null) _ = orderBy(query);

     return (query.Count() != 0) ? await query.Select(selector).ToListAsync() : null;
 }
```

**Example:**

```
var q = await conector.RepositoryBase<TEntity>().FindByConditionAsync<TResult>(
    s => new TResult(){ prop1 = s.prop1 , etc.. },
    f => //Condition,
    o => o.OrderBy(i => i.prop),
    i => i.Include(i => i.prop1).ThenInclude(t => t.innerprop1)
          .Include(i => i.prop2).ThenInclude(t => t.innerprop2)
);
```